# Counting facebook messages

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hey guys am using facebook js sdk to retreive the number of messages send.The code is

```
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {

  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}


}



  function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});


}



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
appId      : '289533237896176',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                    // the session
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });



};




  (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));




  function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me/inbox?limit=50',function(response) {  for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
var thread = response.data[i];

for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
    var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message;

console.log(comment);

}





}

}



);





}



</script>




<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,read_mailbox" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">

<div id="fb-root"></div>

</div>
```

This succesfully retrievees the messages ..But what i need is to find the number of messages send ..I have tried `comment.length` but it didnt helped..I want to find the total number of messages send.

My json object is http://pastebin.com/dnc9U4zN

Can this be done with js sdk ??..Hope you guys can help me ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**obj** is your json object:

```
var numberOfMessages = 0;

obj.data.forEach(function(value){
    value.comments.data.forEach(function(value2){
        numberOfMessages++;
    });
});

console.log(numberOfMessages);
```

Comment: Yes it did. It counts messages as you have requested.